# How to get or write any foreign script into Latin script(english)?

Tags: python-3.x, translation, google-translate, google-translation-api

In python from the `googletrans` module I was able to translate Kannada word `ಬೆಳಗೆದ್ದು` to English `in the morning` but if translated online from google translator it will also show the English pronunciation `Beḷageddu` under the word `ಬೆಳಗೆದ್ದು`. Does anyone have an idea how to get English pronunciation of any foreign scripts from the `googletrans` module or any other modules?